# Trying to teleport members in a certain team in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am creating a server in Minecraft and I would like to make it when a player gets to a certain area it teleports the members of a certain team to a different location.

I would also like to know how to separate different areas for commands in different worlds so say you use a command block in one world it will not effect anyone in the other worlds.

Also how if possible to set it so you can have different games in the same world but none of the commands will work from one game to the other.

Comment: You could try this plugin : https://bukkit.org/threads/inactive-mech-party-v0-6-use-party-system-for-your-plugins-674.9033/ and this one also http://bukkit.org/threads/inactive-tp-partytp-v0-2-teleports-members-of-a-party-party-support-674.9425/ if an update is needed, try contacting the developper.

Comment: @Hybris95 those plugins are 4 years old and are probably not what OP wants (likely vanilla teams)

Comment: @Darron Boladeras maybe precise if the request is on vanilla teams or any kind of team system ?

Answer (score 2):

Thats a lot of questions! 
1. testfor a player in the specific location, then do */tp @a[team=**Teamname**] **x y z*** 
 2.Just make a scoreboard */scoreboard objectives add world dummy **World*** and give entities and players in each area a different score */scoreboard players set @a[r=**range**] world **4*** and then, on every command put [score_world=**4**] target selector for any entity. 
 3.That the same thing *if I got it right...* 
 + anything in **bold** means you can change it however you need to